# curl problems in c++ class

Tags: c++, curl

I read a few articles on c++ / curl here on stackoverflow and assembled the following. 
The main goal is to handle the whole request in an instance of a class -- and maybe later in a secondary thread.

My problem is: "content_" seems to stay empty though its the same addr and

HttpFetch.h:

```
class HttpFetch
{
private:
    CURL *curl;
    static size_t handle(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * p);
    size_t handle_impl(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb);
public:
    std::string content_;
    static std::string url_;
    HttpFetch(std::string url);
    void start();
    std::string data();
};
```

HttpFetch.cpp:

```
HttpFetch::HttpFetch(std::string url) {

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    content_.append("Test");
    std::cout << &content_ << "\n";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content_);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &HttpFetch::handle);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //tell curl to output its progress
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    //std::cout << &content_ << "\n";
}

void HttpFetch::start() {

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

size_t HttpFetch::handle(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * p)
{
    std::string *stuff = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(p);

    stuff->append(data, size * nmemb);

    std::cout << stuff << "\n"; // has content from data in it!

    return size * nmemb; 
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "HttpFetch.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    HttpFetch call = *new HttpFetch("http://www.example.com");
    call.start();

    ::std::cout << call.content_ << "\n"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. The main problem is the line

```
HttpFetch call = *new HttpFetch("http://www.example.com");
```

You create a new HttpFetch instance and copy it to another one. So you have two instances  and two content strings. To remove this issue change it to:

```
HttpFetch call("http://www.example.com");
```

Another error is the line

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);
```

which should be

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

You could have avoided such issues if you had thought about resource managment in a class like HttpFetch. Since HttpFetch manages a resource (a curl handle) you have to think about how to initialize and cleanup this resource an how to handle copy, assignment or move. If you use C++11 the easiest solution is to use a `std::unique_ptr` which handles all that stuff for you.

```
class HttpFetch
{
public:
    HttpFetch(const std::string& url);
    void start();
    void Print(std::ostream& stream);
private:
    typedef void (*cleanup)(CURL*);
    typedef std::unique_ptr<CURL, cleanup> CurlHandle;

    CurlHandle curlHandle;
    std::string content_;

    static size_t handle(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * p);
};


HttpFetch::HttpFetch(const std::string& url) 
    : curlHandle(curl_easy_init(), &curl_easy_cleanup)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle.get(), CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content_);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &HttpFetch::handle);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle.get(), CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
}

size_t HttpFetch::handle(char * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * p){
    std::string *stuff = static_cast<std::string*>(p);
    stuff->append(data, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb; 
}

void HttpFetch::start() {
    content_.clear();
    curl_easy_perform(curlHandle.get());
}

void HttpFetch::Print(std::ostream& stream){
    stream << content_;
}

int main()
{
    //HttpFetch call = *new HttpFetch("...");  // this is a copiler error now
    HttpFetch call("http://www.google.com");
    call.start();

    call.Print(std::cout);
}
```

Using a `unique_ptr` your class HttpFetch becomes uncopyable and movable only. This makes sense until you provide logic to copy or share an CURL handle between different instances of HttpFetch.